# What is the lifespan of Betazoids?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

What is the lifespan of Betazoids? Is it the same as humans or longer? I remember Lwaxana Troi always being intentionally vague about her age, supposedly out of vanity. I don’t remember any of the few Betazoids we see actually making any references to age or longevity. Are we ever told?

Comment: The only reference I found so far is at [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Betazoid), which gives a lifespan of 160-175 years for females and 150-165 years for males. Memory Beta also gives a human lifespan of 120 years, so Betazoids generally live longer than humans. No sources/references are provided, therefore, it's just a comment.

Comment: *TOO DAMN LONG*

Comment: Memory Beta is also not canon.

Comment: Yes...I remember from TNG that we (Terrans) by then had an expected  lifespan of 140 yrs, with 85 being considered to be the beginning of old age, so I know that Memory Alpha isn't always right.

Comment: If recent pictures of Marina Sirtis are any indication, they age extremely well!

Comment: @JohnRose quite frankly same for Gates McFadden. Dr Crusher definitely took care of herself, what being a top-notch medical professional and all.